# How to display/render OGC WFS web service on Google Maps using Google Map JavaScript API v3

Tags: wfs, web-service, google, ogc, google-maps-api-3

I want to display publicly available OGC web services on Google Maps. I figured out the solution for WMS but no clear solution for WFS.

Sample WFS: http://services.ga.gov.au/geoserver/boreholes/ows?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&

Comment: my mistake- http://services.ga.gov.au/geoserver/boreholes/ows?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: More WFS example at - https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=wfs&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc

Comment: Without going through all the example WFS, is it correct to say that the WFS you cite only support EPSG::4283 as the CRS?

Comment: In theory you can request GeoJSON through a GetFeature request like: `http://services.ga.gov.au/geoserver/boreholes/ows?version=1.1.0&typename=boreholes:Boreholes&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&outputformat=application/json&` but the problem here is that the output doesn't follow the current GeoJSON specification (that is CRS is not correct...)